# PEP 354-like implementation of enums

Tags: python, enums, pep

At one point enums were considered by the Python developers to add to the language, but they dropped the feature. Is there some implementation of the [PEP 354](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0354/)? — the specification seems pretty robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/ is the implementation of this PEP.

Answer (score 0):

The PyPI package [enum](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0354/#enum-package) provides a Python implementation of the data types described in this PEP.

Also, an [implementation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flufl.enum/) by Barry Warsaw.

Finally, [PEP 435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) has been accepted for Python 3.4, the backport is [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the advanced version is [aenum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum).